# session get expired in the third page PHP

Tags: php, session

I have a problem that the session expires between the pages(in third page) or when I refresh , 
that's the first page

```
<?php
session_start();

if(empty($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['password']))
{
    $this->HandleError("Missing username or password");
    return false;
}

$username = stripslashes($_POST['username']);
$password = stripslashes($_POST['password']);

$con = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1' , 'root' , '' , 'Mini');

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) 
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$query = " SELECT * FROM User WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password'";
$result = mysqli_query($con , $query);
$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if($count == 1)
{
    $_SESSION["username"] = $username;
    $_SESSION["login"] = 1;
    header("location:HomePage.php");
} else {
    session_destroy();
    header("location:Welcome.php");
    echo "Wrong username or password";
}
mysqli_close($con);
 ?>
```

second one :

```
<?php 
session_start();

if (!(isset($_SESSION["login"]))) 
{
    header ("Location: Welcome.php");
    exit();
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="Welcome.css"/>
        <title>eShop Hompage</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <div id="right-corner">
                <img id="logo" src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQWgR8v763Veku3oLPsw7mqU7bKpSVu2nSXfMPZA8RrxEiDoRuF_Q">
                <p id="p1">eShop</p>
                <p id="p2">your virtual shop</p>
            </div>
            <div id="welcome">
                <h3>Welcome <?php echo $_SESSION["username"]; ?> </h3>
            </div>
            <a href="Edit.php">Edit info</a>
            <a href="Welcome.php">Logout! <?php session_destroy(); ?></a>
        </header>
        <hr style="margin-top:45px;">
        <div class="items">
            <?php
                $con = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1' , 'root' , '' , 'Mini');
                if (mysqli_connect_errno()) 
                {
                    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
                }
                $query = "SELECT * FROM Item";
                $result = mysqli_query($con , $query);
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
                {
                    echo "<img src=".$row['pic']."/>";
                    echo "<p>".$row['name']."</p>";
                    echo "<p>".$row['price']."$"."</p>";
                    if($row['quantity'] > 0)
                    {
                        $id = $row['id'];
                        $link = "Buy.php?item=".$id;
                        echo "<a href=".$link.">Buy</a>";
                    } else {
                        echo "Sold out!";
                    }
                    echo "<br>";
                    echo "<br>";
                    echo "<br>";
                }

             ?>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The problem comes when I go to a third page , it acts if I'm logged out and session expired :

```
<?php 
session_start();

if (!(isset($_SESSION["login"]))) 
{
    header ("Location: Welcome.php");
    exit();
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="Welcome.css"/>
        <title>eShop Hompage</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <div id="right-corner">
                <img id="logo" src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQWgR8v763Veku3oLPsw7mqU7bKpSVu2nSXfMPZA8RrxEiDoRuF_Q">
                <p id="p1">eShop</p>
                <p id="p2">your virtual shop</p>
            </div>
            <div id="welcome">
                <h3>Welcome <?php echo $_SESSION["username"]; ?> </h3>
            </div>
            <a href="Edit.php">Edit info</a>
            <a href="Welcome.php">Logout! <?php session_destroy(); ?></a>
        </header>
        <h5>Are you sure you want to buy?</h5>
        <?php
                $con = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1' , 'root' , '' , 'Mini');

                if (mysqli_connect_errno()) 
                {
                    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
                }
                $id = $_GET['item'];
                $query = "SELECT * FROM Item WHERE id = '$id'";
                $result = mysqli_query($con , $query);
                $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
                $name = $row['name'];
                echo "<p>".$name."</p>";
                echo "<img src=".$row['pic']."/>";
        ?>
        <a href="HomePage.php">Yes 
            <?php 
                $con = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1' , 'root' , '' , 'Mini');

                if (mysqli_connect_errno()) 
                {
                    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
                }
                $id = $_GET['item'];
                $quantity = $_GET['quantity'];
                $query = "UPDATE Item SET quantity = quantity - 1  WHERE id = '$id'";
                mysqli_query($con , $query);
             ?>
            </a>
        <a href="HomePage.php">Cancel</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: instead of having it redirect on the third page have it print_r($_SESSION) for you to see that it's actually gone, or if something was changed in it. Assuming nobody has access to this page yet.

Comment: You are using mysqli but your code still vulnarable for sql injection. Try prepared statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is in your code @ second page:

```
<a href="Welcome.php">Logout! <?php session_destroy(); ?></a>
```

You are destroying the session, so by the time the third run goes in the session doesn't exist.

I think what you want is an actual fourth page (call it logout.php) which will contain the `session_destory()` part and update your second and third pages logout to:

```
<a href="logout.php">Logout!</a>
```

Comment: From what I understande , I have to destroy the session when logging out

Comment: Yes but your destorying it no matter what. Aziz just saw that code when your answer poped up beat me to it.

Comment: Refer to this document: http://php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php which will help you understand how PHP works with HTML. Once you place PHP code on the page it will execute.

Comment: @user3626926 In fact, the session is being destroyed in the second page for the reasons Aziz explains in the answer.